# Memory Leak in io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext in Java Application

Tags: java, memory-leaks, vert.x

We are using vert.x toolkit (for building reactive applications on the JVM) in one of our Java Application. Past few days we have started seeing high memory (heap) usage which sometime results into application unresponsive (due to heavy GC CPU cycle usage). So to investigate whats eating heap memory I've used Eclipse MAT tool for finding memory leaks. This what it shows :

[image]

Not sure what actually going wrong in the code so need experts advise here. Please find my pom and vertex code below. Let me know if you need other details. I'm following this guide [vertex.io guide](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/) & [vert.x java code e.g](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/)

**Pom.xml**

```
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
```

**Request Handler Code using io.vertex :**

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.container.Suspended;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.WorkerExecutor; 

public class Processor {

private static final Map<String, WorkerExecutor> executorMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public WorkerExecutor getWorkerExecutor(String threadName, Vertx vertxObj) {
    WorkerExecutor executor = executorMap.get(threadName);
    if (executor == null) {
        synchronized (Processors.class) {
            executor = executorMap.get(threadName);
            if(executor == null){
                executor = vertxObj.createSharedWorkerExecutor(threadName);
                executorMap.putIfAbsent(threadName, executor);
            }
        }
    }
    return executor;
}

@POST
@Path("/update_record")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public void processUpdateEvent(String data, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @Context Vertx vertx) throws Exception{
    logger.info("update called");
    WorkerExecutor executor = getWorkerExecutor("update_record_event", vertx);
    executor.executeBlocking(future -> {
        MyProcessor processor = (MyProcessor) MainClass.context.getBean("myprocessorevent");
        try {
            processor.processMessage(data);
            future.complete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("consuming event failed: " + e.getMessage());
            future.fail(e);
        }
    }, res -> {
        Response response  = null;
        if(res.succeeded()) {
            response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
        } else {
            response = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
        asyncResponse.resume(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Funny thing is, you are not accomplishing anything, or technologically favoring your stack by using Vert.x in that example...except using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved now!

> Actually there was a memory leak to all the versions before 3.5.2.CR2 ;
>   For more insight check this issue reported :
>   https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/issues/2464 and [fixed commit id](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/commit/37f281bee87f212e80dd5b5520cef0ff7bad56fb) .

So very soon [vert.x](https://vertx.io/download/) will launch its 3.5.2 version publicly. Thanks to [vert.x community](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/vertx/Xagd_SthFoo).